# Why does PrintWriter work for outputting to Process, but BufferedWriter does not?

Tags: java, linux, terminal

I have code similar to the following that interacts with gdb from Java. I start the process with gdb and then get the process's streams. I have a thread that constantly reads the output of the process (using `procOut`) and prints it to the screen, and I send commands to gdb using `procIn.println("some_command")` -

```
Process proc = new ProcessBuilder("gdb").start;

procOut = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
procErr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getErrorStream()));
procIn = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(proc.getOutputStream())));
```

However if I change `procIn` to a BufferedWriter -

```
procIn = BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(proc.getOutputStream()));
```

and use `procIn.write("some_command")`, it doesn't work and gdb doesnt get the input. Anyone know why this happens?

Comment: Did you try to call `flush()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to do a flush() on the BufferedWriter to make sure it goes out.